# MYSQL - Join only the lastest row from the second table

Tags: php, mysql

I have patients table and appointments table. I want to query appointments from today and join patient info on the query.

This

```
SELECT a.PatientID, a.DoctorID, a.DT, 
p.id, p.Name 
FROM appointment a 
JOIN Patient p 
ON p.id = a.PatientID 
WHERE DATE(DT) = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY a.DT DESC
```

Works, but it shows the first row it finds (usually the older one) not respecting the order by (to show only the latest by patient). What am I missing here?

UPDATE:
Sorry, I should write it more properly.

Patient table:

```
id Name
1  Jonathan
2  Helena
```

Appointment table

```
PatientID DoctorID DT
1         1        2021-08-27 09:30
2         1        2021-08-27 10:00
1         1        2021-08-27 11:00
```

If I query as I have it, the return will be

```
  1         1        2021-08-27 09:30
  2         1        2021-08-27 10:00
```

Instead of

```
2         1        2021-08-27 10:00
1         1        2021-08-27 11:00
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but have you tried `ORDER BY ReturnDate DESC`??

Comment: It's hard to help you without sample data and a desired resultset. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window function for retrieving the patient wise latest date record. Then join patient table. If all patient info is needed then use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT p.id PatientID
     , p.Name patient_name
     , t.DoctorID
     , t.DT
FROM Patient p
INNER JOIN (SELECT PatientID
                 , DoctorID
                 , DT
                 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY DT DESC) row_num
            FROM Appointment) t
        ON p.id = t.PatientID
       AND t.row_num = 1
ORDER BY t.DT;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=944f2dd72105bc9fb06b1a6b5fd837f2

For lower version where window functions are not supported.

```
-- MySQL(v5.6)
SELECT p.id PatientID
     , p.Name patient_name
     , tmp.DoctorID
     , tmp.DT
FROM Patient p
INNER JOIN (SELECT @row_no := IF(@prev_val = t.PatientID, @row_no + 1, 1) AS row_number
                 , @prev_val := t.PatientID PatientID, t.DoctorID, t.DT
            FROM Appointment t,
           (SELECT @row_no := 0) x,
           (SELECT @prev_val := 0) y
           ORDER BY t.PatientID, t.DT DESC) tmp
      ON p.id = tmp.PatientID
     AND tmp.row_number = 1
ORDER BY tmp.DT;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d665ffe9f3d09df23513ad50be31b388

Comment: @NuM3 please check the result and let me know if any question.